# Problem with long running rake task incl. rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rabbitmq

Let's see if i can explain this problem structured enough.

I run a webservice that handles email sending asynchronously using RabbitMQ and a ruby lib called [Minion](https://github.com/orionz/minion). On certain models (like a comment) we have an after create hook that adds an email-event to Rabbit. This event is then processed through a worker that runs as a rake task, [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/865976), that loads the appropriate user and sends the email.

This setup works in 90% of the cases but every now and then the worker crashes due to an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception. But how is this possible, I queue the event after the object is created and it takes additional ms for the event to pass through the Rabbit layer. Could it be that the context of the rake task causes the problem? Is it a bad choice to run long running workers within rake with the environment flag? Help! :)

Comment: the only problem that might happen with rake task with environment might be change of code, that is related, so when you deploy changed code you need to restart the rake task, useful here might be unicorn with using script/runner

Comment: Sure, we do a restart with every deploy...

Comment: I'm guessing it's the the user in which the RecordNotFound exception is being thrown, but the newly created model (comment).  I'm guessing you are passing the id to rabbitmq in order to load the model.  Are you sue the correct id is being passed in these instances of the crash?

Comment: Right, yes, it's most probably the comment causing the crash. And yes, it's the right id.